# Java Android Manually Project Creation

Tags: java, android

I have few questions:

- Is it possible to create an Android App with Java and setup all
  myself?
- If yes, what are the important things, that must a App have?
- Is there a tutorial?

If someone want know why:
I want to understand all exactly and want to have the full control.

The Android SDK with eclipse have so many features(For the first small projects too many).
In the best case I want only link the Android library jar, but I think its not so easy and there are a few Mord things Like the App manifest ...

I hope someone understand me and can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to understand all exactly

I doubt that there is anyone on the planet that understands it all exactly.

> Is it possible to create an Android App with Java and setup all myself?

I do not know what "with Java" means here. Based on the rest of your question, I am interpreting this as:

> Is it possible to create an Android application project without an IDE?

In that case, you are welcome to:

- Create a project using **`android create project`**, designed to be built with Apache Ant, or
- Create a project by copying an existing project or downloading a bootstrap project, then use **`android update project`** to create the Ant build files

> If yes, what are the important things, that must a App have?

The **`android create project`** command will create a complete "Hello, world" application, ready to be run.

> Is there a tutorial?

I will settle for pointing you to the [documentation for creating and building projects on the command line](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html), in hopes that perhaps that is what you are referring to.